# What is difference between combination and composition?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I understand the difference between permutation and combination. But how is composition different from combination ?

Edit:
I am referring to this [Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics))

Comment: What's your definition of "composition"? It's not a standard term in combinatorics (though it is in other mathematical contexts).

Comment: Maybe the OP means composition of permutations, though the question should be edited to make this clearer.

Comment: Edited my question. Please check now

Comment: Is it not clear to you from the link you provided ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is how to find the number of compositions of $n = 8,\;$ say.

Take a string of eight 1's enclosed in parentheses, (11111111)

Now place either a +, or a special symbol,$\;$ )+($\;$ between the 1's, e.g.

(1+1)+(1+1+1)+(1)+(1+1)

Since you have $2$ choices for each gap between the $1's,$ # of compositions = $2^{n-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Compositions are permuted integer partitions. They are integer partitions with considering the order of the parts.